# Internal Server Error in WebConnection call

Tags: delphi, iis

I have a Delphi application using WebConnection to connect to server (IIS Web Server, mapping httpsrvr.dll). In local IIS Server there is no problem. In production server, when calling a method, after 30 seconds a Internal Server Error (status code 500) is returned, but the connection itself is not lost, and the method continue to execute in the server.

Before, we faced problem with timeout error, also after 30 seconds. We resolved by setting INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT and INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT parameters of wininet.

I think this error is returned by IIS, but I dont know if is a IIS problem (some configuration), or a problem with httpsrvr.dll, and IIS cant figure out and returns 500 error.

I tried to set `executionTimeout` in IIS configuration, nothing changed.

We are tring to reproduce the production environment here, but in the mean time, can someone help with ideas?

Comment: IIS often adds another number, ex 500.13 Web server is too busy which could help diagnose what the issue is. Also if your server side code is slow to start it could cause timeouts - IIS will often shutdown apps that haven't been accessed in a while so the next request could be very slow to service.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Learn the substatus code from IIS log files first.

Comment: There is no substatus code in this case, just 500

Comment: try to use the IIS failed request tracing and process monitor to troubleshoot the issue. [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) ,[link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)